# Upload File in MVC gives null Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am really new to MVC,

Please help me to upload file in MVC 5 ASP.NET. I did all exactly as it was suggested in similar questions on SO:

Domain class is:

```
    public class Business
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string CityID { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```

Create view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ....
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file" })
```

In Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Business _business)
        {
            if (_business.File.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(_business.File.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/Uploads"), fileName);
                _business.File.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

But this gives me a Null Ref Exception on _business.File.ContentLength... However other parameters passed OK.

Just any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute to the `<form>` element?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, i tried, no success, the same null exc happens

Comment: The you have not added it correctly. Show the code for generating the form element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke here's the code:

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Comment: Which is wrong! (its adding a route value, not a html attribute) And you need to edit the question, not in comments

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot! You're awesome!!! Updated the question

Comment: Answers do not go in the question (and its been duped anyway). I included the code you should have included.